# How to append data inside the first list into the second list

Tags: python, python-3.x

How to append data inside the first list into the second list and eliminate newline for data in y.
For example,
y = ['2\n']
x = ['22 34 55 \n']

expected output :
output = [' 2 22 34 55 \n']

I have tried .join syntax but i didnt get the output as I expected.

Comment: Have you tried `x = y + x`?

Comment: Why is there a `\n` not in quotes at the end of the lists

Comment: And why has the `\n` been removed from the string in the first list, in the second list

Comment: Thank you for the bringing that up,, i have edited my questions. I am trying to eliminate the new line in data y,, then concatenate data y which is 2 with data x into a new list.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to merge two lists into one you can use Mechanic pig's method:

```
y = ["2"]
x = ["22", "34", "55"]

z = y + x

# y and x will remain ["2"] and ["22", "34", "55"]
# z will be ["2", "22", "34", "55"]
```

If you are trying to append values to a list you can use the list.extend method:

```
y = ["2"]
x = ["22", "34", "55"]

y.extend(x)

# x will remain ["22", "34", "55"]
# y will become ["2", "22", "34", "55"]
```

Or if you want to prepend a list to a list insert the elements of list y from back to front into x:

```
y = ["2"]
x = ["22", "34", "55"]

for element in y[::-1]:
    x.insert(0, element)

# x will become ["2", "22", "34", "55"]
# y will remain ["2"]
```

EDIT:

After the question got edited, this is my new answer:

```
y = ["2\n"]
x = ["22 34 55\n"]
output = []

for x_elem, y_elem in zip(x,y):
  output.append(y_elem.strip("\n") + " " + x_elem)

# the output will be ["2 22 34 55\n"]
```

The `zip(x, y)` function combines the two lists so it can be used in a for loop. By iterating over every element of both lists and removing the newlines of the element of y. To do this I used the `strip` attribute of a string wich removes characters at the end and start of a string. In this case the newline (`\n`) is removed at the start and end After the removal of the newlines we can combine the y element with the x element while inserting a space inbetween the two strings.

Comment: Thank you so much,, learnt some new knowledge from this! However, i have edited my question.. im trying to get output like this -> Output = [ '2 22 34 55 \n'] :)

Answer (score 0):

We can use the `extend()` method and combine both the lists.

We can also use a lambda function to iterate the list x, and *append* the item as shown.

[image: Python Code Combining 2 Lists.]

---

I have attached the code below.

```
y=[2]
x=[22, 34, 55]

y.extend(x)
print(y) # prints [2, 22, 34, 55]

y=[2]
y.extend([i for i in x])
print(y) # prints [2, 22, 34, 55]
```